# Static component doesn't rerender doing setState

Tags: reactjs

I have this static Content component that doesn't rerender

```
  static Content = ({ children, tabId, activeTab }) => {
    return tabId === activeTab ? children : ''
  }
```

tabId and activeTab is exposed using React.cloneElement.

```
render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        handleTabClick: this.handleTabClick,
        tabId: this.props.id,
        activeTab: this.state.activeTab
      })
    );
  }
```

But I've no clue why the tab 1 content doesn't hide when I click on the tab 2 title.

**Here's the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/w2mxm3zjq5**

Comment: Actually I recommand you to change the logic you are following... The state containing the activeTab must be a part of `Tabs` rather  than the   `Tab` itself

Answer (score 0):

Since your Tab component stores that state, when it is clicked only that particlular compontent state updates and hence the other one doesn't change, you need to lift the state up to the tabs component and it will work.

```
class Tab extends Component {
  static Title = ({ children, handleTabClick, tabId }) => {
    return <div onClick={() => handleTabClick(tabId)}>{children}</div>;
  };

  static Content = ({ children, tabId, activeTab }) => {
    console.log(tabId, "a", activeTab);
    return tabId === activeTab ? children : "";
  };

  render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        handleTabClick: this.props.handleTabClick,
        tabId: this.props.id,
        activeTab: this.props.activeTab
      })
    );
  }
}

class Tabs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeTab: this.props.activeTab
  };

  handleTabClick = id => {
    this.setState({
      activeTab: id
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { children, activeTab } = this.props;
    return React.Children.map(children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        activeTab: this.state.activeTab,
        handleTabClick: this.handleTabClick
      })
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs activeTab={1}>
      <Tab id={1}>
        <Tab.Title>Tab 1</Tab.Title>
        <Tab.Content>Tab 1 content goes here</Tab.Content>
      </Tab>

      <Tab id={2}>
        <Tab.Title>Tab 2</Tab.Title>
        <Tab.Content>Tab 2 content goes here</Tab.Content>
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  );
};
```

**[Working codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/rmq9qkox1n)**